# Does Redis ever return a RESP array of anything other than bulk strings?

Tags: redis

The [RESP Documentation](https://redis.io/topics/protocol#array-reply) specifies how an array that contains items of any other RESP type should be interpreted. However as far as I can tell every command that returns a RESP array will always returns an array of bulk strings. So, I'd like to know if there are any commands that return a RESP array that is not an array of bulk strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example [COMMAND](https://redis.io/commands/command) or [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan).